# Problems with Master/Slave and HRD

Tags: google-app-engine

After a migration from Master/Slave to HRD (High Replication Datastore) using xxx and xxx-hrd both applications have a status running.
But the webpage is not available.

How can I get the webpage back, up and running.

Is there a possibility to go back to the situation before the migration?

Answer (score 0):

At any time before clicking "Finish Migration" you can click "Pause Migration" and click "Revert Migration" to revert the migration. Please see the [docs on migrating to the HRD datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration#potential_migration_issues).

If you've finished the migration you won't be able to revert the migration. You may have run into an issue regarding the differences between the Master/Slave datastore and the HRD datastore. Another possibility is that you have run into an issue with the migration. I encourage you to look at the logs for each application to find out what is going wrong.

Many things cannot be migrated properly like serialized datastore and blobstore keys. Please see the [docs on potential migration issues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration#potential_migration_issues) for details.